# File uploading with Express 4.0: req.files undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I'm attempting to get a simple file upload mechanism working with Express 4.0 but I keep getting `undefined` for `req.files` in the `app.post` body. Here is the relevant code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
//...
app.use(bodyParser({ uploadDir: path.join(__dirname, 'files'), keepExtensions: true })); 
app.use(methodOverride()); 
//...
app.post('/fileupload', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.files); 
  res.send('ok'); 
});
```

.. and the accompanying Pug code:

```
form(name="uploader", action="/fileupload", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
    input(type="file", name="file", id="file")
    input(type="submit", value="Upload")
```

**Solution**
Thanks to the response by [mscdex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2050455/mscdex) below, I've switched to using `busboy` instead of `bodyParser`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
//...
app.use(busboy()); 
//...
app.post('/fileupload', function(req, res) {
    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        console.log("Uploading: " + filename); 
        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/files/' + filename);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {
            res.redirect('back');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: how does this work with multiple files?

Comment: @chovy it should work just fine with multiple files

Comment: ithink it is possible to do app.post('/fileupload',busboy(), function(req, res) {

Comment: Good solution I just wanted to note that you have to create a `./files/` directory in your app's home directory otherwise you will get an error after you upload.

Comment: How are temp files handled? Does busboy delete them automatically? I just don't see anywhere temp files being deleted before saving to disk.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

The [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) module only handles JSON and urlencoded form submissions, not multipart (which would be the case if you're uploading files).

For multipart, you'd need to use something like [`connect-busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy) or [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) or [`connect-multiparty`](https://github.com/andrewrk/connect-multiparty) (multiparty/formidable is what was originally used in the express bodyParser middleware). Also FWIW, I'm working on an even higher level layer on top of busboy called [`reformed`](https://github.com/mscdex/reformed). It comes with an Express middleware and can also be used separately.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Although I had to use `connect-busboy` instead of just `busboy`. Updated my original post with the solution.

Comment: Thanks mate! I find `connect-multiparty` option best of these!

Comment: Is `reformed` still under development? Your last commit on github is from 2014...By the way, in your opinion, what's the best module to handle multipart form data? By "best" I mean the best supported and the one that works better (less bugs), with more features and with a longer future..I chose `multer` because it seemed the best supported, but I still think it should be more supported.

Comment: [EDIT: it'ls ok, just saw the answer below.] did multipart with in express 3.0, and then broken in 4.0? i ask because this tutorial uses 3.4.8 and can upload files without the need for any extra middleware http://blog.robertonodi.me/simple-image-upload-with-express/

Comment: @thetrystero The github repo for that particular example you linked to actually has the dependencies checked into the repo. If you dig through those dependencies you will see Express 3.x is included, as well as Connect 2.x (which still had a multipart module bundled with it). That is why multipart handling was working "out of the box."

Comment: Hello @mscde, 

Can you please see to this issue that I'm facing ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74173460/req-file-and-req-files-are-undefined-when-calling-the-endpoint-from-mobile-apps

Answer (score 61):

Here is what i found googling around:

```
var fileupload = require("express-fileupload");
app.use(fileupload());
```

Which is pretty simple mechanism for uploads

```
app.post("/upload", function(req, res)
{
    var file;

    if(!req.files)
    {
        res.send("File was not found");
        return;
    }

    file = req.files.FormFieldName;  // here is the field name of the form

    res.send("File Uploaded");


});
```

Comment: too slow for large files

Answer (score 24):

1) Make sure that your file is really sent from the client side. For example you can check it in Chrome Console:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHkQ4.png)

2) Here is the basic example of NodeJS backend:

```
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const app = express();

app.use(fileUpload()); // Don't forget this line!

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.files);
   res.send('UPLOADED!!!');
});
```

Answer (score 14):

It looks like `body-parser` *did* support uploading files in Express 3, but support was dropped for Express 4 when it [no longer included Connect as a dependency](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-4.html#core-changes)

After looking through some of the modules in mscdex's answer, I found that [`express-busboy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-busboy) was a far better alternative and the closest thing to a drop-in replacement. The only differences I noticed were in the properties of the uploaded file.

`console.log(req.files)` using **body-parser** (Express 3) output an object that looked like this:

```
{ file: 
   { fieldName: 'file',
     originalFilename: '360px-Cute_Monkey_cropped.jpg',
     name: '360px-Cute_Monkey_cropped.jpg'
     path: 'uploads/6323-16v7rc.jpg',
     type: 'image/jpeg',
     headers: 
      { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="file"; filename="360px-Cute_Monkey_cropped.jpg"',
        'content-type': 'image/jpeg' },
     ws: 
      WriteStream { /* ... */ },
     size: 48614 } }
```

compared to `console.log(req.files)` using **express-busboy** (Express 4):

```
{ file: 
   { field: 'file',
     filename: '360px-Cute_Monkey_cropped.jpg',
     file: 'uploads/9749a8b6-f9cc-40a9-86f1-337a46e16e44/file/360px-Cute_Monkey_cropped.jpg',
     mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
     encoding: '7bit',
     truncated: false
     uuid: '9749a8b6-f9cc-40a9-86f1-337a46e16e44' } }
```

Answer (score 10):

[multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) is a middleware which handles “multipart/form-data” and magically & makes the uploaded files and form data available to us in request as request.files and request.body.

installing multer :- `npm install multer --save`

in .html file:-

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
    <input type="hidden" name="msgtype" value="2"/>
    <input type="file" name="avatar" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

in .js file:-

```js
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.files); // JSON Object
  next();
});

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server successfully running at:-', port);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/file-upload.html');
})

app.post('/upload', upload.single('avatar'),  function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files); // JSON Object
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Please use below code

```
app.use(fileUpload());
```

Comment: var fileupload = require("express-fileupload");
app.use(fileupload());

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to answers above, you can streamline the use of `express-fileupload` to just a single route that needs it, instead of adding it to the every route.

```
let fileupload = require("express-fileupload");

...

//Make sure to call fileUpload to get the true handler
app.post("/upload", fileupload(), function(req, res){

...

});
```

Comment: Took me more than a dozen timeouts to realize you forgot to call the middleware correctly.

Comment: @veteri, true...

Answer (score 2):

A package installation needs for this functionality, There are many of them but I personally prefer "express-fileupload". just install this by "npm i express-fileupload" command in the terminal and then use this in your root file

```
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
app.use(fileUpload());
```

Answer (score 2):

I added multer as global middleware before methodOverride middleware,
and it worked in router.put as well.

```
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
}).single('featuredImage');
app.use(upload);

app.use(methodOverride(function (req, res) {
  ...
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `express-fileupload` npm package to decode files like

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fileUpload({useTempFile: true}))
```

Note: I am using cloudinary to upload image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFOJ8.png)

Answer (score 1):

const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");

router.route("/uploads").post(fileUpload(), uploadProductImage);

//Adding fileUpload() middleware in routes worked for me.

Comment: Hi, there is already an answer with this suggestion. When answering an old question, be sure to add something  useful and above all original. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED !!!!!!!**

Turns out the `storage` function DID NOT run even once. 
because i had to include `app.use(upload)` as `upload = multer({storage}).single('file');`

```
 let storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, './storage')
          },
          filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            console.log(file) // this didn't print anything out so i assumed it was never excuted
            cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
          }
    });

    const upload = multer({storage}).single('file');
```

Answer (score 0):

With Formidable :

```
const formidable = require('formidable');

app.post('/api/upload', (req, res, next) => {
  const form = formidable({ multiples: true });

  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    res.json({ fields, files });
  });
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable

Answer (score -3):

`express-fileupload` looks like the only middleware that still works these days.

With the same example, `multer` and `connect-multiparty` gives an undefined value of *req.file* or *req.files*, but `express-fileupload` works.

And there are a lot of questions and issues raised about the empty value of *req.file/req.files*.