# Node js HTTPServer/StaticServlet POST request

Tags: node.js, angularjs, http, post

I am relatively new to Node js.

I have built Node js / Angular Application based on [angular-requirejs-seed](https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed.git)

However, I found scripts/web-server.js confusing as I used to develop node js server with express.

Particularly, I want to implement file upload, but at least, I want to know how I can implement POST request handler within scripts/web-server.js

```
function main(argv) {
  new HttpServer({
    'GET': createServlet(StaticServlet),
    'HEAD': createServlet(StaticServlet)
  }).start(Number(argv[2]) || DEFAULT_PORT);
}
```

Please guide me in correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

The node server in `angular-requirejs-seed` is not there to act as a fully-fledged webserver - only to sever the files in the seed project.  You'll need to write your own backend (especially if you want to use `express`).

express 4 no longer supports file uploads, so you'll need to use a different package.  I recommend [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy).  ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23118138/1216976))