# Upload file with node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I try to do simple upload in node.js, So I upload a file via my browser, and my server should get this file.

I have the next methods:

```
app.post('/saveDocument', function  (req, res){
    var fileName = req.body.name;
    fs.readFile(req.file,  function (err, data) {
        fs.writeFile("./myStorage/" + fileName, data, function (err) {
        });
    })
    FileServer.prototype.returnRes(res, 200);
});
```

and my HTML is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="uploadForm"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="/saveDocument"
      method="post">
  <input type="file" id="userPhotoInput" name="displayImage" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<span id="status" />
<img id="uploadedImage" />


</body>
</html>
```

I get the next error: `TypeError: path must be a string`

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, you must manage the multi-part form.
See this answer : [File uploading with Express 4.0: req.files undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114374/file-uploading-with-express-4-0-req-files-undefined)