# TypeError: Cannot call method 'end' in simple node file upload

Tags: node.js, upload

Below is a reference to a simple file upload implementation using the 'connect-busboy' module. I am using an Express setup with Backbone frontend structure.

[File uploading with Express 4.0: req.files undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114374/file-uploading-with-express-4-0-req-files-undefined/)

I attempted to use this above method for creating a simple file upload and I keep receiving this error:

```
_stream_readable.js:483    
    dest.end();
         ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'end' of undefined
    at IncomingMessage.onend (_stream_readable.js:483:10)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:180:16)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Doing some research I am getting fixes that are irrelevant to my code. I have implemented this solution exactly as defined above with the exception that I am not using a Jade template builder. In addition, I am running the node server off of localhost. Would this cause an issue?

If anyone can help that would be great. Thanks!

P.S. I copy and pasted the code from the original changing only the route and ending redirect in which both are not causing the issue (the server is properly seeing the request come in via the route and it never reaches the redirect since none of the console logs are output.

EDIT - Added code below

***server.js route***

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
...
app.use(busboy());
...
app.post('/list', function(req, res) {
    console.log("HIT - hasher!");  
    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        console.log("Uploading: " + filename); 
        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/uploads/' + filename);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {
            res.redirect('lists');
        });
    });
 });
```

***list.html template***

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../list/" method="post" data-abide>
...
<span id="ulbtnview">File Upload</span>
<input id="uplbtn" type="file" class="upload" required>
<small class="error">A valid list file is required.</small>
...
<div class="large-5 columns">
<input id="uploadfile" type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" style="padding-right: 1.5rem; padding-left: 1.5rem; padding-top: 0.5rem; padding-bottom: 0.6rem;"></div>
...
</form>
```

**SOLUTION**

The issue is that I needed a 'name' attribute on my input element. Without that the form will process but it will not send the data to the server.

*from*

```
<input id="uplbtn" type="file" class="upload" required>
```

*to*

```
<input id="uplbtn" type="file" class="upload" name="file-new" required>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls

Comment: Show us your code -- `dest` isn't being defined correctly

Comment: I strongly recommend using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) if you're using express.

Comment: You need to provide more information in order for anyone to be able to reproduce the problem. How are you submitting your form? If you're using the browser, what does the HTML for the form look like? If using something else, what's the command line? What node version are you using?

Comment: updated question with code. thanks!

Comment: When you solve your own problem, you should post your own solution as an answer and then accept it. This way, it's easier for people to realize that this question has been answered and refer to your answer in the future.

Comment: @nicolas - I would if stackoverflow let me but i have to wait 8 hours to do so as a new member. It's not going to be on the forefront of my mind by that time but i still want people to see the answer haha. But thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case where I get the same error. I mistakenly defined my router before putting `app.use(busboy());`. After I changed that, the code did work perfectly.