# Using req.files for multiple uploads

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, express

So i am handling a multiple file upload on my client side, where my html looks like the following

```
form(method='post', enctype='multipart/form-data')#createReportForm
  input(type='file', multiple='multiple', accept='image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg', name='uploadImages', data-max-size='5000000')#uploadFile
```

Now on my server side to access the contents of the file and other info i am using 
**req.files.uploadImages**. This works fine if one file attached, but when multiple files are attached on the client this object only reads the last attached file and not the first one

Whats the reasoning behind this? Shouldn't req.files.uploadImages have info about both the files?

Answer (score 0):

If multiple files are selected the `req.files.uploadImages` would hold all the files.

You can just loop over them:

```
var files = [].concat(req.files.uploadImages);
for(var x = 0; x < files.length; x++){
   // upload file
}
```

Comment: But req.files.uploadImages doesn't hold all the files it only recognizes one of the files

Comment: Maybe have a look at this answer which might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23118138/2217519

Comment: doesn't look like the issue is with the middleware