# Saving and Loading Images in MongoDB 2015 using GridFS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, gridfs

I am using nodeJS and mongoDB to create a data entry form. Part of this form requires the user to upload an image. I have found a resource that allows you to do this but now this code is deprecated.

```
app.use(express.bodyParser((uploadDir: __dirname + '/public/uploads')));
```

I have tried using `busboy` as suggested here
 [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114374/file-uploading-with-express-4-0-req-files-undefined)

This saves the file into the upload directory but obviously not to mongoDB.

Youtube video [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fa9Ca4eUr0c)

The result of the youtube video is exactly what I need for my website. I just need to know the code that will make this possible now that body parser is deprecated in express.

Here is my full nodeJS code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var fs = require('fs');
var GridStore = mongo.GridStore;
var Server = mongo.Server;
var ObjectID = mongo.ObjectId;
var Db = mongo.Db;
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');

var server = new Server('localhost',27017,{auto_reconnect:true});
var db = new Db('exampleDb',server);

db.open(function(err,db){
    if(err)
    {
        console.log('Couldnt connect to mongo');
    }else{
        console.log('Connected to Mongo');
    }
});

    //app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    //app.use(express.bodyParser((uploadDir: __dirname + '/public/uploads')));
   // app.use(bodyParser({uploadDir: __dirname + '/public/uploads'}));

app.use(busboy());

//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
//    extended: true
//}));

app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + "index.html" );
});

app.post('/upload',function(req,res){
    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        console.log("Uploading: " + filename);
        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/assets/uploads/' + filename);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {
            res.redirect('back');
        });
    });
console.dir(req.file);
});



app.listen(3000);
```

Update:

I have managed to get it working for uploading but viewing the picture I am still having the following issue:

> MongoError: file with id 55d5a3416aebd290131ca6d2 not opened for writing
>   c:\MyProjects\gridFStesting\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:97
>       process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
>                                           ^
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'stream' of undefined

Here is my updated code:

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var fs = require('fs');
var GridStore = mongo.GridStore;
var Server = mongo.Server;
var ObjectID = mongo.ObjectId;
var Db = mongo.Db;
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');

var db = new mongo.Db('testing',new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1",27017));
var gfs = Grid(db,mongo);

db.open(function(err,db){
    if(err)
    {
        console.log('Couldnt connect to mongo');
    }else{
        console.log('Connected to Mongo');
    }
});

    //app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
    //app.use(express.bodyParser((uploadDir: __dirname + '/public/uploads')));
   // app.use(bodyParser({uploadDir: __dirname + '/public/uploads'}));

app.use(busboy());

//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
//    extended: true
//}));

app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + "index.html" );
});

app.post('/upload',function(req,res){
    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename);
        var gfsstream = gfs.createWriteStream('pic');
        file.pipe(gfsstream).on('finish', function() {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
            console.log(gfsstream);
        });
    });
   // var gridStoreWrite = new GridStore(db,new ObjectID(),req.files.pic.name,"w",{chunkSize:1024,metadata:{}})
//console.dir('testing');
});

app.get('/image/:id',function(req,res){

    var id = req.params.id;
    var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    var outPutFromDbFile = __dirname + '/public/uploads/' + id + '.png';
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(outPutFromDbFile);

   // var BSON = require('mongodb').BSONPure;
   // var o_id = BSON.ObjectID.createFromHexString(id);

    var o_id = ObjectID(id);

    var gridStore = new GridStore(db,o_id,"r");
    gridStore.open(function (err,gridStore){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log('error' + err);
        }

        var readStream = gridStore.stream(true);
        readStream.on("end",function(){
           console.log('close was called');
            res.sendFile(outPutFromDbFile);
        });
        readStream.pipe(writeStream);
    });

});

app.listen(3000);
```

The error only happens some of the time. So I don't know what is causing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [`gridfs-stream`](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream) module, you can do something like this:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');

// create or use an existing mongodb-native db instance
var db = new mongo.Db('yourDatabaseName', new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017));
var gfs = Grid(db, mongo);

// ...

req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
  console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename);
  var gfsstream = gfs.createWriteStream('/uploads');
  file.pipe(gfsstream).on('finish', function() {
    console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixes my problem I hope it helps anybody stuck in the future with this issue.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var fs = require('fs');
var GridStore = mongo.GridStore;
var Server = mongo.Server;
var ObjectID = mongo.ObjectId;
var Db = mongo.Db;
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');

var db = new mongo.Db('testing',new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1",27017));
var gfs = Grid(db,mongo);

db.open(function(err,db){
    if(err)
    {
        console.log('Couldnt connect to mongo');
    }else{
        console.log('Connected to Mongo');
    }
});

    //app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
    //app.use(express.bodyParser((uploadDir: __dirname + '/public/uploads')));
   // app.use(bodyParser({uploadDir: __dirname + '/public/uploads'}));

app.use(busboy());

//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
//    extended: true
//}));

app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + "index.html" );
});

app.post('/upload',function(req,res){
    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename);
        var gfsstream = gfs.createWriteStream('pic');
        file.pipe(gfsstream).on('finish', function() {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
            console.log(gfsstream);
        });
    });
   // var gridStoreWrite = new GridStore(db,new ObjectID(),req.files.pic.name,"w",{chunkSize:1024,metadata:{}})
//console.dir('testing');
});

app.get('/image/:id',function(req,res){

    var id = req.params.id;
    var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    var outPutFromDbFile = __dirname + '/public/uploads/' + id + '.png';
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(outPutFromDbFile);

   // var BSON = require('mongodb').BSONPure;
   // var o_id = BSON.ObjectID.createFromHexString(id);

    var o_id = ObjectID(id);

    var gridStore = new GridStore(db,o_id,"r");
    gridStore.open(function (err,gridStore){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log('error' + err);
        }

        var readStream = gridStore.stream(true);
        readStream.on("end",function(){
           console.log('close was called');
            res.sendFile(outPutFromDbFile);
        });
        readStream.pipe(writeStream);
    });

});

app.listen(3000);
```