# TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;thumbnail&#39; of undefined

Tags: node.js, multer

This is my server.js file
I am trying to find upload image on server. I came to know that multipart doesn't work now.

```
var config=require('./config');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var morgan=require('morgan');
var nodemailer=require('nodemailer');
var fs=require('fs');
var FB=require('fb');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
//app.use(express.bodyparser({uploadDir:'./uploads'})); //This is showing error.
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use('/public',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


mongoose.connect(config.database,function(err){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('database connected');
});

app.listen(config.port,function(err){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('server running at  '+config.port);

});

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname +'/public/app/views/index.html' );
});
app.post('/file-upload', function(req, res) {
    // get the temporary location of the file
    var tmp_path = req.files.thumbnail.path;
    // set where the file should actually exists - in this case it is in the "images" directory
    var target_path = './public/images/' + req.files.thumbnail.name;
    // move the file from the temporary location to the intended location
    fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // delete the temporary file, so that the explicitly set temporary upload dir does not get filled with unwanted files
        fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send('File uploaded to: ' + target_path + ' - ' + req.files.thumbnail.size + ' bytes');
        });
    });
});
```

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/file-upload">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="file" name="thumbnail">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

It is showing the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;thumbnail&#39; of undefined
```

How to upload the image now? I am using this for the first time. I came to know that multer is used now. But how and where to use it in my code?

Comment: What are the values of ```tmp_path``` and ```target_path```?

Comment: tmp_path is the path given by the user to upload the file and target_path is where the gets stored finally.

Comment: I get that, but are they undefined? That is the only place in the code provided that I can see a possible error. Unless you have more code that goes along with that form on the front end.

Comment: undefined as in? It is defined as : var tmp_path = req.files.thumbnail.path;

Comment: If you console.log ```tmp_path``` and/or ```target_path``` what does your terminal say?

Comment: It is giving error. The terminal is not printing anything except the error.

Answer (score 0):

The body parser middleware that you are using does not support multipart (file uploading). It only supports JSON or url encoded form submissions. I am going to point you in the direction of [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114374/file-uploading-with-express-4-0-req-files-undefined). It talks about the same issue you are having.

**SOLUTION**: You need different middleware that supports multipart submission.