# Best way to save files node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm triying to **upload** an **excel** **file** with **postman** and save it in to a folder with `node.js` `fs`:

```
var file = req.body.file;

        fs.writeFile("public/myExcelFile.xlsx", file, function(err) {
           if(err) {
               res.json(err);
           } else {
                res.json("The file was saved!");
           }
         });
```

But when I try to open the file after upload it is corrupt or empty,
can you tell me pls what im doing wrong?

In the future I have to upload another files like .**docx** or .**csv** so I want to know what is the best way to save these files, it's better **save** files in database(I´m using Sql server) as a `blob` ? or save the file in a folder and **save** the **path** in database?

Comment: What libraries do you use? How is your POST encoded (multipart, urlencoded, ...)? Maybe you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114374/file-uploading-with-express-4-0-req-files-undefined

Comment: Thank you @Marc, im using post multipart/form-data, ill try to use connect-multiparty

Comment: just to add on in growing discussion, don't save files into project, it'll drastically grow your project size, instead use CDN, cloud storage and only save path in db, and retrieve data from cloud when even needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using node.js streams. I believe it's best to only save the path in the database.