# Check if image is submitted or not using node.js and multer

Tags: node.js, multer

I am able to upload images but if i need to edit my page where sometimes I need not upload a newer image, how do I proceed?

I am checking using the below code but every time its giving me "undefined".

```
    router.post('/update/:id', function(req, res, next) {

    var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, "./uploads/images");
        },
        filename: function (request, file, callback) {
            callback(null, file.originalname);
        }
      });

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
      if (typeof req.files.image !== "undefined") {
        // code
      } else if (typeof req.files.image === "undefined") {
        // code
      }

    home.update(req.files[0].path, req.body.input_field_name, req.params.id);
      req.flash('edit', 'Updated.');
      res.redirect('edit/' + req.params.id);
    });

    });
```

Any help?

**Solution**

```
upload(req, res, function (err) {
  if (typeof req.files !== 'undefined' && req.files.length > 0) {
      //code
  } else {
      //code
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you provide some more context?

Comment: @Hartger I have included the full code. Please check. Basically, I want to check if I am uploading any image or not. In both the cases, the code must work.

Comment: what does console.log(req.files) output for you? Perhaps checking on the length of req.files would work. Are you using bodyparser btw?

Comment: @Hartger console.log(req.files) gives me "undefined". Yes, I am using "bodyparser".

Comment: Appearantly bodyparser no longer supports file uploads. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114374/file-uploading-with-express-4-0-req-files-undefined

Comment: @Hartger But I am able to upload. The problem is I need to validate whether I am uploading a file or not. As I am using multer, is there anyway to validate using multer?

Comment: Shouldn't req.files be req.file?

Comment: @Hartger req.files and req.file, both are showing "undefined".

Comment: When you define upload, do you define it as multer().single(fieldName)?

Comment: @Hartger i am defining upload as: var upload = multer({ storage: Storage }).array("image", 1);

Answer (score 1):

```
   if (typeof req.query.image !== "undefined") {
        // code
        console.log("File is uploaded");
      } else if (typeof req.query.image === "undefined") {
        // code
        console.log("File is not uploaded");
      }
```

//if you are using post then use - req.body.image

Comment: Its giving me: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined".

Comment: Install - 'npm install --save body-parser' and then add these lines in code - 

var bodyParser =    require("body-parser");
var app =   express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: In both the cases, its going to else statement.

Comment: u r using get or post

Comment: i am using post