# Unable to upload a file express(NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I was facing this tiny issue in a sample NodeJS application I was creating, that I always receive `req.files` as undefined even though I am uploading a file via postman.
Here's the code:

```
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';


let app = express();


app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    let files = req.files;
    res.send(files);
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, () => {
    console.log(`Started on port 8000`);
});
  
export default app;
```

And here's how I am sending the file via postman:
[image]

But I still get and empty response and also as logging on cmd I get the output as undefined:
[image]

Would be greatful if anyone could help.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114374/file-uploading-with-express-4-0-req-files-undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to upload files, I recommend using multer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

But if you don't want to use multer or bodyparser, you can stream the data:

```
req.on('data', data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

You can pipe the stream to write to file. check fs documentation.