# Angularjs ng-file-upload not getting the data on my api endpoint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm creating an upload img service. My problem is that I can't seem to get the data from my endpoint.

I'm using `ng-file-upload` and `multer`

**HTML**

```
<div class="button" ngf-select ng-model="vm.uploadedImages" name="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-max-size="20MB"
ngf-min-height="100" ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}">Select</div>


<button class="btn btn-primary btn-raised btn-sm" ng-click="vm.test()">save</button>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
vm.test = function () {
  console.log(vm.uploadedImages); // img getting the data

  Upload.upload({
    url: 'api/getTest', //webAPI exposed to upload the file
    data: { file: vm.uploadedImages } //pass file as data, should be user ng-model
  });
};
```

**ROUTES**

```
router.post('/getTest', function (req, res) {
    console.log('req', req.body); // getting blank value 
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

Comment: it seems like your path is wrong `api/getTest` in angular conttroller and node controller '/getTest' both needs to be same

Comment: @ParthRaval its triggering though so i think that's not the problem

Comment: this will help you this is a basic answer :-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114374/file-uploading-with-express-4-0-req-files-undefined/47826310#47826310

Comment: If you are using `multer`, your routes should look like this. `router.post('/getTest', upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
    console.log('req', req.file); // // req.file is the `file` file
    res.send(req.file);
});`