# Multer Doesn't Save Images on Disk In Any Way

Tags: node.js, express, multer

It simply doesn't save anything to the `destination` folder i specified.

i tried `{storage:storage}` instead of `{dest: 'storage/'}` but it didn't work either.
the image data is actually sent to the server as its console logged. and the `dest` i specified is created by default but remain empty.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');
    let storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: '/public/my-uploads',
          filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
          }
    });

const upload = multer({dest:'storage/'}).single('file');


app.post('/upload', upload, (req , res) => {
  console.log(req.files) // this does log the uploaded image data.
})


***** EDIT ******
```

`HTML`

```
        <form  onSubmit={this.upload} enctype='multipart/form-data'>
          <input type='file' name='image' />
          <input type='submit' value='upload' />
        </form>
```

`JS`

```
  upload(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const file = e.target[0].files[0];
    console.log(file)
    const fm = new FormData();

    fm.append('file', file);
    console.log(fm)
    axios.post('/upload', fm);
  }
```

`POSTMAN`

[image]

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114374/file-uploading-with-express-4-0-req-files-undefined/47826310#47826310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, the issue was that I wasn't using the multer middleware at all so the callback code for handling the image was never executed.
I didn't know much about how express worked back then.

Comment: hi @Biss can you let me know how did you fix this? i'm having the same issue. How did you use the middleware?

Answer (score 1):

Try to catch the error my calling the middleware yourself:

```
var upload = multer().single('avatar')
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // An error occurred when uploading
      return
    }

    // Everything went fine
  })
})
```

Also, change the storage to this:

```
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, ca) {
        cb(null, '/public/my-uploads');
    }
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried before and tried now again. theres NO ERROR printing!! but it doesn't actually save anything to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not using the storage variable and use a function for the destination key, as written in the documentation, also you need to pass your file in the input field named `field` otherwise multer can't store the file, create an storage folder on the same level as the code :

```
const http = require('http')
const port = 3000
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');
const server = http.createServer(app)

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './storage')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage }).single('file');


app.post('/upload', upload, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files) // this does log the uploaded image data.
})

// bind the server on port
server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('something bad happened', err)
    }
    console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

[image]

Comment: Yea, same problem.

Comment: did use the field `field` in your form for send the file ? @SharlSherif

Comment: you need to pass your file in the input field named `field` otherwise multer can't store the file

Comment: the name of the form field should be file

Comment: jesus!! i have the same exact code and it only creates the folder and nothing else..

Answer (score 0):

The name of the "single" in `...single('file')` must match the name in the input (containing the file) `<input type="file" name='image' />` - and it does not in your example.

Change the multer-part to this `...single('image')` - as in the input `name='image'`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try this File Storage For Save image in Local**

```
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "images");
      },
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(
          null,
          new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-") + "-" + file.originalname
        );
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create folder /public/my-uploads first then you can save your file. I am currently learn nodejs and face this issue.

Comment: HI, maybe you solved your problem creating that directory, but there is a completely different answer, marked as accepted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).