# While sending routes and data to server side from client . I'm not recieving data on server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic3

I'm trying to upload the file to server. currently I'm uploading images. 
**This is my client side code**

```
 onClickfileupload(){
    let data={};
    let path="";
   let api_url = '/api/uploadFileFromIonicHome';
    this.fileChooser.open()
    .then(uri => 
    { 
      path= JSON.stringify(uri);
      alert(path);

   data={
      userEmail: this.userEmail,
      userName: this.userName,
      userRole: this.userRole,
      fileComment: this.desc,
      type: "file",
      fullFileName:'file-'+Date.now()+'.jpg'
  } 
  this.imagesProvider.uploadImage(path, data, api_url).then((res) => {
    let dataPassedBackObj = {
      reload: true,
      pathOfFile: path,
      typeOf: "picture",
      userName: this.userName, 
      fileComment: this.desc
    }
    alert("Successfully uploaded picture...");
    this.events.publish('toggleMenu');

  }, err => {
    alert(err.http_status);

    alert("There was error in uploading picture...");

  }); })
    .catch(e => alert(e));
    }
```

This is my provider what I'm using to upload the file to server side.
**This is my providers code**

```
     uploadImage(img, data ,api_url) {
    alert("Uploading file...");
    // Destination URL
    let url = SERVER_HOST + api_url;
    // File for Upload
    var targetPath = img;
    console.log("line 28"+targetPath);
    var options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: 'image',
      chunkedMode: false,
      mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
      params: data,
    };

    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    return fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, url, options);
  }
```

This is my server side code where I'm getting the routes. but req. body is coming empty {}.
**This is part of my server side code**

```
app.post('/api/uploadFileFromIonicHome', uploadFromHome.single('image'), function(req, res) {
console.log('within /api/uploadFileFromIonicHome');
console.log(req.body.type);
console.log(req.body);
var userName = req.body.userName;
var userEmail = req.body.userEmail;
var userType = req.body.userRole;
var fileName = req.body.fileName;
var type = req.body.type;   
var comment = req.body.comment;
var fileComment = req.body.fileComment;
```

*I'm getting empty "req.body" 
 and "req.body.type is undefined."*
This the error I'm getting
**typeerror:cannot convert object to primitive value**

Comment: Please look into : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114374/file-uploading-with-express-4-0-req-files-undefined .  OR https://medium.com/technoetics/handling-file-upload-in-nodejs-7a4bb9f09a27

Comment: You get file in `console.log("req",req.files);
  var filesArray = req.files;
  `

Comment: I'm getting req.files as undefined , and req.body as { }

Comment: are you using `connect-multiparty` or `multer` module?

Answer (score 0):

> Use `connect-multiparty` to read files. Reference [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-multiparty)

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();

app.post('/upload', multipartMiddleware, function(req, resp) {
  console.log(req.body, req.files);
  // don't forget to delete all req.files when done
});
```

Comment: It's still not working for me. I have tried what you have suggested.