# Edit page image upload concept using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express, file-upload

Am new in `Nodejs`, In my project am trying to upload image in `Edit page`.

Here am using two conditions, those are following:

1. If user select image file means
2. With out selecting

> If user select image file new image `upload` and save it in my `database.`
>
> else save old_image data without `upload file`.

This is my code:

```
router.post('/edit_coupon/:id', verifyToken, function(req, res, next){
    let update_coupon = {};
    var file = req.files.image;
    if(Object.keys(req.files).length != 0) // if user select file
    {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (999999 - 100000 + 1)) + 100000;
        const image_name = random+file.name;
        file.mv('public/assets/images/coupons/'+image_name, function(err){
            if (err)
            {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
        });
        update_coupon.image = image_name;
    }
    else
    {
        update_coupon.image = req.body.old_image;  // if user didnot select file
    }

    // code for update 
    ...
    ...
    ...

});
```

My above code not working when user without select image showing error
like

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>       at Function.keys ()

Comment: This question smells like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114374/file-uploading-with-express-4-0-req-files-undefined, try if the answer there helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the `req.files` is available and it's a type of object or not using `if` statement and `typeof` operator as follows:

```
router.post('/edit_coupon/:id', verifyToken, function(req, res, next){
    let update_coupon = {};
    var file = req.files.image;
    if(req.files != null && typeof req.files == 'object') {
     if(Object.keys(req.files).length != 0) // if user select file
     {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (999999 - 100000 + 1)) + 100000;
        const image_name = random+file.name;
        file.mv('public/assets/images/coupons/'+image_name, function(err){
            if (err)
            {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
        });
        update_coupon.image = image_name;
    }
    else
    {
        update_coupon.image = req.body.old_image;  // if user didnot select file
    }

   }

    // code for update 
    ...
    ...
    ...

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your code its working fine can you please explain this line `if(req.files != null && typeof req.files == 'object')`

Comment: `req.files` is an object, you should check whether the `req.files` is available using` req.files != null` and then you should check the type of the `req.files` whether it is object or not using the `typeof` operator. If the answer solves your problem mark it as solved.