# sending file via fetch with formData to Nodejs server returns req.files null

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, multipartform-data

I have always sent files along with form data by having the action attribute and multipart enctypes to my html forms. Recently I needed to use fetch to send a form and used the `new FormData()` can read all my fields and file of a given html form. But on the `nodejs` end, req.files returns `null`. When I use form `action` attribute, it works perfectly.

**Client End**

```js
let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('additem'));
let response = await fetch(`${window.location.href}/inventory`, {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        });
```

On the server end I am just using `express-bodyparser` (which is default now) and am trying to access the files with `req.files`;
I know I can use `multer` or `formidable` but I was wondering if there's a way to make it work with what I have atm.
Thanks.

Comment: The body parser dosn't handle multipart uploads for file uploads. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23118138/5781499

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the server end I am just using express-bodyparser (which is default now) and am trying to access the files with req.files; I know I can use multer or formidable but I was wondering if there's a way to make it work with what I have atm.

No, there isn't. `FormData` objects generate multipart bodies.

See [the documentation for body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and
>   typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in
>   the following modules:
>
> - busboy and connect-busboy
> - multiparty and connect-multiparty
> - formidable
> - multer

Answer (score -1):

where are your `Content-Type` if you are going to send a file you need to specified
on them headers, by default the content-type is application/json

there is good example at the Mozilla Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: `fetch` will automatically set the correct Content-Type when passed a `FormData` object. You **can't** set the Content-Type for a FormData object manually because you don't know what value the mandatory `boundary` parameter needs to have.

Comment: Oh! thats right, then how come you are having this issue‍♀️  just tell me to paste the code so you can do copy/paste of it

Comment: Yeah. I've read that it can cause issues if you define content type with formData. It's something to do with setting boundaries.

Comment: @Ernesto — They are having the issue because they are using body-parser which doesn't support multipart requests.