# Why is req.file undefined in my route.post?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, multer

I am trying to send a photo from react to node server.

But i have some problems : req.file is undefined and I don't understand why

This is my react code

```
const formData: any = new FormData();

formData.append("file", {
  uri: image.uri,
  type: image.type,
  name: "tmpImage",
});

try {    
  await axios.post(`${BACKEND_URL}/recipes/photo`, {
    formData,
    header: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
  });

} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error when sending image");
}
```

and here is my nodejs code

multer conf :

```
export const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    console.log("here dest");
    callback(null, "uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    console.log("here filename");
    callback(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

export const upload: any = multer({ storage });
```

route :

```
recipesRoutes.post(
  "/photo",
  upload.single("tmpImage"),
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log("req files =>", req.files);
    console.log("req file =>", req.file);

    return res.status(200).send();
  }
);
```

express conf :

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
```

req.file is undefined and I don't understand why.

Thanks for help

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format.

Comment: Probably you need some middleware to handle files sent as a form-data. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114374/file-uploading-with-express-4-0-req-files-undefined)

Comment: Already tried bodyparser. Same result. But im gonna try asap again

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the different curly brackets for the data that you are sending
and the headers that you configuring. it must be something like this:

```
 await axios.post(`${BACKEND_URL}/recipes/photo`,
       {formData},
       {header: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }},
 );
```

based on this example :

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.post('https://httpbin.org/post', {x: 1}, {
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
 }
 }).then(({data}) => console.log(data));
```

on this page

[GitHub](https://github.com/axios/axios)